# Safari rendering problem

Tags: css

can anyone help with this....  http://www.apolloensemble.co.uk  ....looks like the problem is the menu bar but I'm fairly new to this and am not sure.  Its fine in FF and IE (7 & 8).  Tried various cross-browser issue checks but can't find anything that looks significant.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From [`SpryMenuBar.js`](http://www.apolloensemble.co.uk/SpryAssets/SpryMenuBar.js):

```
Copyright (c) 2006.
```

Look like they didn't take into account that Safari has been improved the last few years. I see several browser checks and browser-specific hacks which aren't applicable anymore nowadays. The web keeps changed, the techniques get improved quickly. This all can just be done with only CSS.

Contact the original authors for an update. If in vain, create one yourself with help of CSS (great Google keywords: ["css suckerfish menu"](http://google.com/search?q=css+suckerfish+menu)) or maybe with [jQuery](http://jquery.com).

Comment: Hi, thanks - will try to get update, its ridiculous how long this sort of thing takes to sort out.  Thanks also for the keywords.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the padding of the menu ul. It has a -webkit padding of somesort. if you can edit the css change the following:

```
ul#MenuBar1 {
  padding: 0;
}
```